# Select Single node using child node containing specific innertext. XMLDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

Hello I am working on XmlDocument retrieval

part of my document is

```
 <Product ID="102166"> 
        <Name>Name1</Name> 
         <Mrp>220.0000</Mrp> 
         <Price>210.2800</Price> 
          <Cost>177.8700</Cost> 
         <Barcode>102166,10216610,8901786409990,9910216600011,10216620,9910216600202
    </Barcode>
 </Product>
```

I want to select single product  node from document whose itemcode inner text contains given string

e.g If I give 8901786409990 as input output should be its parent i.e. Product with ID 102166

I have tried following with no success

```
string ItemCode="8901786409990 ";
 XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/*/b:Product[contains(b:Barcode,'" + Itemcode1 + "')");
```

It throws exception `'/*/b:Product[contains(b:,'8901786409990')'` has an invalid token.

Any Help?

Comment: That was by mistake Barcode and Itemcode are same but

Comment: tried but different exception see below comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a close bracket:

```
string ItemCode="8901786409990 ";
 XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/*/b:Product[contains(b:Barcode,'" + Itemcode1 + "')]");
```

See the extra bracket here:

'/*/b:Product[contains(b:,'8901786409990')**]**'

Comment: Now it throws Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function. Any solutions?

Comment: Take out the `b:`, it is a reference to a namespace in XPath syntax.

Comment: Ya its working properly without throwing exception, but even for correct barcode its giving value for node as null, sorry to bother you! :)

Comment: OOps that was my fault. Its working properly. thanx for ur help and support :)